# Laravel: Toggle and checking results

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking to use the toggle method on a many to many relationship.

This is the method I'm currently working on:

```
    public function toggleExerciseToProgram(Program $program, Exercise $exercise)
    {
        $program->exercises()->toggle($exercise->id);

        if ($program->exercises($exercise->id)->exists()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message'  => "Exercise $exercise->name attached to $program->name",
                'exercise' => $exercise,
                'method'   => 'add'
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "Exercise $exercise->name removed from $program->name",
                'method'  => 'remove'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

The issue I am facing is this check:
`$program->exercises($exercise->id)->exists()`
doesn't seem to work. Is my syntax off?

I used tinker which actually gives me a nice response but how can I get that in Laravel?

```
>>> $p2->exercises()->toggle(3);
=> [
     "attached" => [],
     "detached" => [
       3,
     ],
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is quite simple:

`$program->exercises()->where('exercise_id', $exercise->id)->exists()`

Returns a Boolean.